# SMTP Error 530 5.7.57 when sending email from Apache Camel to Office.365

Tags: smtp, apache-camel, office365

Error message: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.0 - 
Apache Camel 2.19.1 - 
JavaMail version 1.4.7 -

--mailer.properties

```
camel.smtpserver=smtp.office365.com:587

camel.smtpUser=xxx@xxx.com

camel.smtpPassword=xxx

camel.smtpfrom=xxx@xxx.com

camel.smtpto=xxx@xxx.com
```

xxx@xxx.com: a valid office365 account

--Camel.xml

```
<to uri="smtp://{{camel.smtpserver}}?password={{camel.smtpPassword}}&amp;username={{camel.smtpUser}}&amp;mail.smtp.auth=true&amp;mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true&amp;from={{camel.smtpfrom}}&amp;to={{camel.smtpto}}&amp;contentType=text/html"/>
```

-- Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to modify your url like below

```
smtp://{{camel.smtpUser}}:{{camel.smtpPassword}}@{{camel.smtpserver}}?mail.smtp.auth=true&amp;mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true&amp;from={{camel.smtpfrom}}&amp;to={{camel.smtpto}}&amp;contentType=text/html
```

The presence of a @ character in the user name can also be critical.

Comment: @SGTech Looks like your question was answered. Why not share some Karma by voting Alexey Yakunin up and marking his anwer as the selected answer.